# Get query results in array of arrays using json_encode in php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to fetch the list of id's associated with mobile number using following code.

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM complaints WHERE mobile=1555521555";

$r = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

$res = mysqli_fetch_array($r);

$result = array();

array_push($result,array(
     "id"=>$res['id']
 )
);

header('Content-Type:application/json');
echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));

mysqli_close($conn);
```

But it only result me a single id every time as below instead of list of id's

```
{"result":[{"id":"82925318"}]}
```

Actual query result is -

[image]

How do I get the multiple results in array of arrays format or in multidimensional array? Like below -

```
{"result":[{"id":"82925318"}, {"id":"82925319"}]}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need loop to get all data

```
$result = array();
while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($r))
{
    array_push($result,array(
     "id"=>$res['id']
 )
);
}
```